# Access Web Page from .ashx WebHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

Quick question.  Is it possible, and if so how do you access the webpage from the webhandlers?

Basically, when i button is clicked i kick off some JavaScript, which then kicks off a C# webhandler which return data from the server.  What i would like to do then is rather than feed it back to the JavaScript, id like to add a GridView directly to the webpage from the webhandler.

Equally, within the handler it would be incredible useful to be able to read values of dropdowns etc from the webpage.

All help or suggestions are welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Comment: Could this not be completed with the AJAX Extensions and an update panel? They allow you to change/transfer "chunks" of a web page

Comment: To be honest, i have no idea.  How would one go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The ***HTTPhandlers*** for **.ashx** and **.aspx** requests are different. These are extension based handlers and the requests are diverted to a particular handler depending upon the extension and are processed differently. You can use both of them but cannot mix them.

*For your specific problem try this*: Add an asp:GridView in the **.aspx** page. Now when your *WebHandler* acquires data, store it in a Session. This Session can then be used as the Data Source for your Grid View.

***Sample Code***

```
public class UpdateDataset : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

{

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    AppointmentsWS.WebServiceConsumerClient objApp = new AppointmentsWS.WebServiceConsumerClient();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = objApp.ScheduleGridSource();
    context.Session["AppDetails"] = ds;
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

*Simple enuff ryt!*

Comment: @CatchingMonkey: Please mark any answer that you feel suitably answers your question or, if you have got a better answer do post it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to get the data from the webhandler to populate the datagrid you want and then create an html table with the data  onsuccess callback javascript function on client side. You may use jquery data table which is quite nice to show your data as a datagrid.

Answer (score -1):

> Equally, within the handler it would
>   be incredible useful to be able to
>   read values of dropdowns etc from the
>   webpage.

Maybe this can help You [Server.Transfer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/avi_sanjay/Server.Transfer.htm06172006162238PM/Server.Transfer.htm.aspx)

Comment: Ive googled it, and my (limited) understanding seems to suggest that this would only work between pages. Im trying to access the page from the handler. is this right?